# How do I run the mysql command from the command line of an AWS RDS instance that is separate from the EC2 instance I am on?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds

We have AWS Amazon Linux EC2 instances that connect to separate AWS RDS instances running MySQL.

We want to run the `mysql` command on the RDS instances to process a number of large SQL files that contain thousands of SQL statements. However, we need to be able to run these commands from a PHP application installed on the EC2 instances.

Is this possible and how can it be done?
For testing, we installed MySQL on the same machine as the PHP application, and were able to successfully run the `mysql` command to query both the localhost MySQL instance as well as the remote MySQL instances on the AWS RDS instances.

However, we're not sure how to do this when MySQL isn't installed and the `mysql` command isn't available on the EC2 instances.

We have explored using the `ssh` command in combination with the `mysql` command, but nothing seems to work yet.
Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should include your PHP code which is working with the MySQL instance co-loclated on the same node.  You should only have to change your connection string to point to RDS, and the rest should still work (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though RDS hosts the `mysql` database you still need the appropriate packages to talk to the database such as `php-mysql`. In addition, the `mysql` package is just the client where `mysql-server` would actually install the server service which you don't need when using RDS. You can safely install `mysql` and `php-mysql` and likely achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Brandon Miller, yes, that did the trick. Thank you. I already had the `php-mysqlnd` package installed, so all I had to do was install the `mysql` package with `yum install mysql`, and it gave me the necessary client to connect to the RDS instance remotely and make requests. Thanks a lot! Didn't think it would be that easy.

Answer (score 2):

For testing, you can install MySQL workbench on the local machine(not on EC2 instance) and configure it to connect to RDS.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-rds-mysql-workbench/

Or, you can also connect to RDS from the command line using command

```
mysql -h mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2015-root.pem -p
```

For detail explanation of above command visit :-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html